# Pattern rotation in graphene

Tags: graphics

[image]

I want to draw this figure in Mathematica 10.1 using code. All arrowhead and dotted lines are not needed. The rotation of two sides is by 30 degree separated by grain boundary.

Comment: Meet us halfway. Can you provide the source of that picture?

Comment: Are you trying to replicate a real scientific data, or just create a similar-looking image? One of these is relatively easy, another probably too specific or out of scope of this site.

Comment: OP's image can be found [here](https://www.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http://www.nature.com/nmat/journal/v9/n10/images/nmat2830-f1.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.pinsdaddy.com/grain-boundary-examples_N1BB7mhT7oQDg9E2XC9BfNrxqujyRhhAqJELHsOq4%7Cc/&h=1128&w=946&tbnid=fXn3E3LsuPxBeM&tbnh=245&tbnw=206&usg=__IWcoQqOrWidM5hX2M6Rn47SSG_E=&hl=fr&docid=FVzJyUT_WLLB2M&itg=1)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a highly unscientific mock-up which is based on finding points of differently rotated triangular meshes on two slightly overlapping regions and computing a Voronoi mesh of the result:

```
ClearAll@centers;

centers[reg_, angle_: 0] := {x, y} /. 
   Solve[{x, y} == 
      u RotationTransform[angle]@{0, 1} + 
       v RotationTransform[\[Pi]/3 + angle]@{0, 1} && (u | 
        v) \[Element] Integers, {{x, y} \[Element] reg, u, v}];

VoronoiMesh[
   Join[centers[Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {5 + 2/3, 14}], -\[Pi]/24], 
    centers[Rectangle[{5 + 1/3, -3}, {14, 14}]]], {{0, 11}, {0, 
     11}}] // MeshPrimitives[#, 1] & // Graphics
```

[image]

Comment: But I want exact 30 degree rotation. It is of 60 degree. On changing value of angle, hexagonal pattern disappears. Also I want just heptagon and Pentagon ring with equal sides.  could you help me please?

Comment: You can change `-\[Pi]/24` to `-\[Pi]/6.` (exact `6` fails for some reason). This is a nonscientific visualization nonetheless; dynamics of graphene atom arrangements are way beyond my expertise. It might be that `MeshPrimitives[#, 0] &` of above Voronoi mesh could be used as a starting point of atoms for some sort of a differential equation system, but I really think that part is more about solid-state physics than Mathematica.